# Rename "Free Shipping" field on checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We have included shipping costs into the cost of the individual products. As such we enabled free shipping, but we want to rename "Free Shipping" text which appears on checkout to say "Shipping Included In Cost of Product" or something similar to that. I don't really know how to create a filter to do this .

I found the verbiage in woocommerce/classes/shipping/free-shipping/class-wc-shipping-free-shipping.php

I also found http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/ but again I don't really know the proper code to create an action / hook to change this text via my functions.php file.

Here is a screen shot to the area of the template I am referring to (link now broken) http://cl.ly/image/0i311G3Y163E

Comment: YOu want to do the change by hook only ?

Comment: I really don't care how it has to be done as long it doesn't involve editing the core woocommerce files. I open to anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    goto => 
 Dashboard =>
 woocommerce => 
 settings =>
 Shipping =>
 Free shipping => 
  Method Title - Change here
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if anyone still needs a solution to this but this can be easily accomplished without any coding through the backend of your Wordpress site.

1. Go to Woocommerce > Settings.
2. Select the tab "Shipping".
3. Hover over the shipping zone you want to edit (or the "locations not covered by other zones") and click on "manage shipping methods".
4. There you will see all shipping methods you have set up and you can simply change the name by clicking "Edit" and changing the Title of the shipping method.