# WooCommerce Free Shipping - Remove raw or change the text name on checkout and email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I am running WooCommerce 2.6.2 on WP 4.5.3 and Sydney template.

On the WooCommerce Checkout Page (Order completed) under Order Details, I want to Change the 'Free Shipping' text to something else, or remove this row.

I also want to change or remove this row from the Emails sent to the Customer.

However, I can't get this text to Translate

I've added this to my functions.php

```
// Add this to your functions.php
add_filter('gettext', 'translate_reply');
add_filter('ngettext', 'translate_reply');

function translate_reply($translated) {
$translated = str_ireplace('Free Shipping', 'TBD', $translated);
return $translated;
}
```

but it doesn't work. That said, if I change just 'Shipping' then it translates the shipping label. I don't want to translate the Label, I want to translate the actual shipping method name.

This is getting frustrating. It don't think it should be this difficult to change a piece of text.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally you don't need any code for this. As there is big changes Since **WooCommerce 2.6+** for **Shipping settings options**, I have divided my answer in 2 sections:

1. **In WC version 2.5 and before *(old way)*:**

In Admin backend go to: **`WooCommerce` > `settings` > `Shipping` > `Free shipping`**

You can:

- Disable free shipping, to remove the row as you asked.
- Rename "Free Shipping" by something else's you asked too.

[image: Free shipping settings for WC 2.5]

2. **In WC version 2.6+ *(It's different)*:**

In Admin backend go to: **`WooCommerce` > `settings` > `Shipping` > `Shipping Zones`**

Then For each **`Shipping Zone`** listed you can have (or not) **`Free Shipping`** Shipping method enabled. So for each **`Shipping Zone`** listed, you can:

- Remove Free Shipping *(by Shipping Zone)*, to remove the row as you asked.
- Rename "Free Shipping" *(by Shipping Zone)* by something else's you asked too.

[image: Free shipping settings for WC 2.6+ (1)]

[image: Free shipping settings for WC 2.6+ (2)]

[image: Free shipping settings for WC 2.6+ (3)]

Reference: [WooCommerce rename "Free Shipping" field on checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139124/woocommerce-rename-free-shipping-field-on-checkout) *(old version until WC 2.5.x)*

Comment: On WooCommerce 3.3.5, it seems the best way to avoid having the words "Free Shipping" is to change it to `Flat Shipping`, but set a custom name and the price to 0.

Answer (score 1):

If it still does not change in the frontend, go to WooCommerce > Status > tools and clear WC transients!